# Receiving a traceback error when doing a flowchart

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, flowchart

I've been asked to make a code that asks the user 3 questions and the user has to input either a 'yes' or 'no' answer, which would then output a response if the user should answer the phone or not. The first question asks the user if they are asleep, if the user inputs 'yes' the output would be 'don't answer', if the input is 'no' the output would ask if it is mom calling. If the answer is 'yes' output would be answer, 'no' and it will ask if it is the morning. If it the input is 'yes' then output would be 'don't answer', if the answer is 'no' it would be 'answer'. 
Here is my code that I created for this, however I am receiving a traceback error regarding stage2 when I input 'yes' when asked if the user is asleep. How would I fix this? (Python)

```
print("Your Cell Phone is ringing")

print("Are you asleep?")
stage= input()
if stage == 'yes':
    print("Don't Answer the phone")
elif stage =='no':
    print("Is Mom calling?")


if  stage =='no':
    stage2= input()
    if stage2 =='no':
        print("Is it morning?")
else:
    print("Answer the phone")

if stage2 =='no':
    stage3= input()
    if stage3 =='no':
        print("Answer the phone")
    else:
        print("Don't answer the phone")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that stage2 is never assigned if you answer 'yes' at the first stage.

Take a look at the structure of your if-statements. stage2 is assigned only if stage == 'no' but at the end it is checked regardless what the previous choice was. You need to change your structure in a way where stage 2 is checked in the right branch only.

```
if stage1 == 'no':
  stage2 = input()
  if stage2 == 'no':
    #do step 3 as well
  else:
    #end reached
else:
  #end reached
```